# Retrieving a ForeignKey attribute based on the URL of the website?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create a function that allows individuals to post something on an associated userpage. I have created both the model ‘newpost’ and ‘newpostform’ (below). I am having trouble writing the view function to look at the current URL of the page and then take that parameter and attach it to the newpost model’s ForeignKey field automatically. For example, if I am at the URL myapp.com/userpage1 and I click on the “post” button on that page, I want to create a newpost object which automatically has the ForeignKey field filled in as ‘userpage1’. Basically, I am trying to create an app where people can easily navigate userpages by entering the userpage parameter into the URL and easily make posts on those pages quickly and concisely - kind of like how reddit's subreddit system works by entering the name of the subreddit into the URL bar. Thanks for any help and hints.

model:

```
class newpost(models.Model):
    newlinktag = models.ForeignKey(‘userpage’) #tags link to which userpage the post belongs to
    postcontent = models.CharField(max_length=1024) 
    postdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) #submission timestamp. 
    postlikes = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=0)  

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.postcontent
```

form:

```
class newpostform(forms.ModelForm):
    postcontentform = models.CharField(max_length=1024)     
    class Meta:
        model = newpost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

urls.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<url_user_id>[\w\-]+)/$', your_view)
```

views.py

```
def your_view(request, url_user_id)
   # you have the foreign key in the url_user_id field.
   ...
   if request.POST:
        new_post_with_foreign_key =  newpost(newlinktag=url_user_id, ...)
        ...
        new_post_with_foreign_key.save()
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble with just the URL mapping portion of the code. Can you explain what [\w\-]+ means? How I did it looks like:


     url(r'^(?P<url_user_id>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*)/comment$'

Comment: I think you want to use + instead of *  ...  \w\- matches word characters and hyphens, so very similar to your solution. I'm not 100% sure why yours doesn't work, but give mine a try.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this in the form. Exclude the FK field from the modelform altogether, and set it in the view on save.

```
if form.is_valid():
    post = form.save(commit=False)
    post.newlinktag = page
    post.save()
```

(You might like to consider following PEP8 and using some CapitalLetters in your class names, and underscore_names in your field names. It'll make your code much easier to read.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. When you say not to do this in the form, do you mean to simply not have a ModelChoiceField in the form and just save the newlinktag field in the model when I have the Modelform completed (which would essentially just be the entered text of the user, right?)

Also, if you could, can you give me some hints on how to do the url mapping correctly? I am having trouble getting my urls.py to properly have a map of the page. Currently I have:

url(r'^(?P<userpagename>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*)/comment$'